# A Star Algorithm - Help on G and H part

Tags: path-finding, heuristics, a-star

I am having a bit of trouble getting the H and G to function properly. What is happening is when I run the program it sometimes finds the best path and sometimes goes way out of the way to get to the location.

Here are some screenshots of what is going on:

[Good path find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwpYH.jpg)

[Bad path find](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc5Ck.jpg)

This is my current setup for F, H and G:

```
public double f(Node current, Node adj, Node goal)
{
    double f = g(current, adj) + h(current, goal);
    return f;
}

public double h(Node current, Node goal)
    {
        double dx = goal.getX() - current.getX();
        double dy = goal.getY() - current.getY();

        double h = Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

        return h;
    }

public double g(Node current, Node adj)
    {
        double dx = adj.getX() - current.getX();
        double dy = adj.getY() - current.getY();

        double g = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(dx) + Math.abs(dy));
        System.out.println("g " + g);
        return g;
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your image links are broken

Answer (score 1):

The G value is the cost from the start to the current node and not just to the adjacent node. At the moment you are more doing a greedy search, just going forward in the shortest direction and not looking back how far you have traveled already.

so you got "cost from start to current" + "(under)estimated cost from current to goal".

Comment: Yes a minor detail I seemed to have overlooked: http://www.policyalmanac.org/games/aStarTutorial.htm

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for maintaining the G value?

Comment: That's not true though. In order for h to be admissable, according to Wikipedia, "the estimated cost must always be lower than or equal to the actual cost of reaching the goal state." Which is the opposite of what you said.

Comment: @Tim Oh man, right! Sorry to all, that was really my memory intriguing me, this makes also more sense. God, never write fast answers 4:00 in the morning. Sorry again.

Comment: @abc123 just store the cost from the start with the node and add the previous node's cost to the cost from the previous node to the next when visiting a new node.

Comment: THANK YOU FOR THIS POST!!!! i am actually working on the same project. where would you use this though?

Comment: Regarding the underestimate property of the heuristic: This is used to encourage A* to try more paths, in order to find the optimal path. See here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/30778/why-is-the-a-search-heuristic-optimal-even-if-it-underestimates-costs